# HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid при подключении к wcf сервису

Tags: c#, wsdl, wcf

Добрый день, помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться в ситуации:

к созданной wcf службе получается успешно подключиться локально

http://localhost:50233/Service1.svc?wsdl

при тестировании соединения с другой машины в локальной сети вижу ошибку 400

http://computer:50233/Service1.svc?wsdl

Нашёл информацию о том, что это может быть связано с MaxFieldLength и в связи с этим
правил реестр, как советуют [тут](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996475(v=exchg.80).aspx#feedback), но к изменению результата это не привело.

Windows 8, Visual Studio 2013, используется встроенный IIS Express, оба компьютера в одном домене.

*Обновление*

```
C:\Users\user>ping computer

Pinging 192.168.0.11 with 32 bytes of data:

Reply from 192.168.0.11: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=127

Reply from 192.168.0.11: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=127

Reply from 192.168.0.11: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=127

Reply from 192.168.0.11: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=127

Ping statistics for 192.168.0.11:

Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),

Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:

Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
```

*Обновление 2*

IP правильный. При остановке службы ошибка на удалённом компьютере меняется на "Веб-страница недоступна". В правилах фаервола разрешил все входящие соединения на порт 50233. При локальном подключении к адресу

```
http://computer:50233/Service1.svc?wsdl
```

Видно ту же ошибку 400. При удалении localhost или замене на IP хоста в записи

```
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:50233:localhost" />
```

Файла `\My Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config` подключение становится недоступно. При добавлении очередного бинда

```
<Binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:50233:localhost" />
<Binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:50233:192.168.0.11" />
```

Служба при попытке запуска ругается на

```
Программа "[9632] iisexpress.exe" завершилась с кодом -1073741816 (0xc0000008) 'An invalid handle was specified'.
```

Comment: `ping computer` с другой машины что говорит?

Comment: А IP правильный? А то имя хоста "computer" несколько подозрительно.

Comment: После выполнения команды 
  C:\Windows\system32>netsh http add urlacl url=http://computer:50233/ user=Все

Ошибка 400 пропала. Зато появилась 503. The service is unavailable.

Comment: После этого я просто добавил бинды к машине

< Binding  Protocol = "http" bindingInformation = "*:50233:computer"  />  
< Binding  Protocol = "http" bindingInformation = "*:50233:192.168.0.11"  />  
< Binding  Protocol = "http" bindingInformation = "*:50233:localhost"  /> 

и всё начало работать!

спасибо всем, это замечательное место

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался.

Выполнение команды

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://computer:50233/ user=Все
```

помогло изменить ошибку на 503.
Теперь, чтобы увидеть мой wsdl я просто добавил в файл
`My Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config`
следующие строки:

```
<Binding Protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:50233:computer" /> 
<Binding Protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:50233:192.168.0.11" /> 
<Binding Protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:50233:localhost" />
```

Ответ дан мной в комментарии выше и здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24255829/3744622